Looking for an alternative to COUNTIFS() that will work with a dynamic range (eg: array output of FILTER() function)
Off the top: this question is similar to others that have been asked, but solutions on those others have not helped me here.
Ex: Using an array formula in countifs range, Using Range as Criteria in Countif, CountIf With Filtered Data
The Ask: Using Excel 365, I am doing matrix multiplication on two frequency-weighted variables in a large table that requires a fair bit of filtering.  Here's a minimal version of my data, a working example of what I'm trying to do, followed by the wrinkle I'm trying to solve:



Row
A-Filter1
B-Filter2
C-Var1
D-Var2




2
1
1
1
10


3
1
1
5
12


4
1
1
1
11


5
1
1
2
12


6
1
1
4
13


7
1
2
5
11


8
1
2
3
12


9
1
2
1
12


10
1
2
2
13


11
1
2
4
14



The steps to do my calc are as follows:
A: Axis1: Frequency of unique values of Var1 where Filter1=1 multiplied by Var1 (to get freq-weighted Var1):

Get Unique Var1,and sort: SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER($C$2:$C$11, ($A$2:$A$11=1) )))
Get count of #1 by value: COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$11, <result of #1>,$A$2:$A$11,1)
Express #2 as a %: <for each of #2> / SUM(<result of #2>)
Multiply #1 by #3 to get Freq-weighted Var1: <result of #1> * <result of #3>

B: Axis2: Frequency of unique values of Var2 where Filter1=1 AND Filter2=1 multiplied by Some value X less Var2 (to get freq-weighted "X - Var2"):
Steps are exactly the same as Axis #1, but adding the extra Filter and the subtracting Var2 from X
C: Matrix Multiply: SUM(<Each ofAxis1:Result #4> * <Each ofAxis2:Result #4>)
D: Multiply Step C by count of Filter1=1 & Filter2=2: <Resulted of Step C> * COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$11, 1, $A$2:$A$11, 1)
The purpose of this math doesn't really matter, but if it helps wrap your head around it you can think of Filter1 = month and Filter2 = day, so we're coming up with a sum of the frequency-weighted occurrence of Var1 in a month to Var2 in a day, across the # of hours in a day.
In any case, I'll save you all the time and share a single equation/function that does exactly what I described above (though I need to transpose one axis to get the matrix-multiplication to work). And I set X = 50:
=SUM(
  (
    COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$11,
                 TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER($C$2:$C$11, ($A$2:$A$11=1) )))),
             $A$2:$A$11, 1)
    / COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11, 1)
    * TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER($C$2:$C$11, ($A$2:$A$11=1) ))))
  )
  *
  (
    COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$11,
                 SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER($D$2:$D$11, ($B$2:$B$11=1)*($A$2:$A$11=1) ))),
             $B$2:$B$11, 1,
             $A$2:$A$11, 1)
    / COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$11, 1, $A$2:$A$11, 1)
    * (50 - SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER($D$2:$D$11, ($B$2:$B$11=1)*($A$2:$A$11=1) ))) )
  )
) * COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$11, 1, $A$2:$A$11, 1)

Result = 537.6
So with that working great and being super fast even on 100,000 rows of data, that brings me to my question:
The above data is simplified. In addition to there being more than two filter columns (easy enough to get around), Var1 and Var2 are, themselves, calculated fields AND need to be filtered up on as well.
I'll just focus on Var1 because the solution will be the same for both: Let's re-write Var1 as: Var1 = MAX(3 - Var1, 0) or to make it more array friendly: Var1 = (Var1<3) * (3-Var1)
If we go back to my larger formula above, that means what I WANT to do is change this:
  (
    COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$11,
                 TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER($C$2:$C$11, ($A$2:$A$11=1) )))),
             $A$2:$A$11, 1)
    / COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11, 1)
    * TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER($C$2:$C$11, ($A$2:$A$11=1) ))))
  )

to
  (
    COUNTIFS(FILTER(3 - $C$2:$C$11, ($A$2:$A$11=1)*($C$2:$C$11<3) ),
                 TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(3 - $C$2:$C$11, ($A$2:$A$11=1)*($C$2:$C$11<3) )))),
             $A$2:$A$11, 1)
    / COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11, 1)
    * TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(3 - $C$2:$C$11, ($A$2:$A$11=1)*($C$2:$C$11<3) ))))
  )

Result = 153.6 (using helper columns)
Everything works except that first line:
COUNTIFS( FILTER(3 - $C$2:$C$11, ($A$2:$A$11=1)*($C$2:$C$11<3) ), ... because obviously COUNTIFS won't accept an array instead of a range. Incidentally, making a range with that formula works, but only if you set it equal to the same # of values as is contained in the full table. In either case, creating a "helper range" isn't practical in my application.
I've tried a variety of combinations of SUM and SUMPRODUCT formulas entered as array-formulas and not, but so far have not found the winning combination.

MMULT can be used to take arrays https://superuser.com/a/1814816/1856315 do you have Office 365 or Excel 2021?

Since you are doing frequencies I suggest replacing Countifs by Frequency as follows:
=SUM(
  (
    TRANSPOSE(DROP(FREQUENCY(FILTER(3 - $C$2:$C$11, ($A$2:$A$11=1)*($C$2:$C$11<3) ),
                 (SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(3 - $C$2:$C$11, ($A$2:$A$11=1)*($C$2:$C$11<3) ))))),-1))

    / COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11, 1)
    * TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(3 - $C$2:$C$11, ($A$2:$A$11=1)*($C$2:$C$11<3) ))))
  )
  *
  (
    COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$11,
                 SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER($D$2:$D$11, ($B$2:$B$11=1)*($A$2:$A$11=1) ))),
             $B$2:$B$11, 1,
             $A$2:$A$11, 1)
    / COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$11, 1, $A$2:$A$11, 1)
    * (50 - SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER($D$2:$D$11, ($B$2:$B$11=1)*($A$2:$A$11=1) ))) )
  )
) * COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$11, 1, $A$2:$A$11, 1)


As mentioned by @P.b, we don't know if you have Excel 2021 or 365. If you can't use Drop to ignore the last element of the array returned by Frequency, you should be able to use Index or in this case filter instead. Using let to avoid repetition:
=SUM(
  (LET(filter,FILTER(3-$C$2:$C$11,($A$2:$A$11=1)*($C$2:$C$11<3)),
   freq,FREQUENCY(filter,(SORT(UNIQUE(filter)))),
    TRANSPOSE(FILTER(freq,freq>0))
    /COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,1)
    *TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(filter))))
  )
*
  (
  COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$11,
   SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER($D$2:$D$11,($B$2:$B$11=1)*($A$2:$A$11=1)))),
     $B$2:$B$11,1,
     $A$2:$A$11,1)
  /COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$11,1,$A$2:$A$11,1)
  *(50-SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER($D$2:$D$11,($B$2:$B$11=1)*($A$2:$A$11=1)))))
  )
 )*COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$11,1,$A$2:$A$11,1
)


Hey @Tom, that worked great (both versions). Thanks for the quick response. Incidentally I AM using Excel 365 (v2403, fwiw). I haven't tried benchmarking both results, but I'm assuming that the first one is probably a bit faster? any thoughts on that?

Glad it worked for you. I would expect the second one to be faster because you are only evaluating the filter once, but not massively.

I've been looking into LET() and LAMBDA() since working through your formulas - they look pretty useful for speeding up many of my workbooks.  I'm a bit surprised that Excel doesn't automatically re-use repeated expressions in a formula to optimize its calculation. Similarly, for example, calculating the results of both the true and false leg of an IF statement regardless of the conditional result

I don't feel qualified to give a general answer, but Microsoft seem quite explicit here https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999 that repeated expressions in an formula are evaluated repeatedly and it is worth using Let to avoid this. It's true that If and ifs are only executed as far as necessary though.

Hey @MJC, though @Tom has provided an answer, I added one because you showed interest in using LAMBDA etc.

Playing with Name Manager, as defining names could be helpful here; with names defined, we could use:
=SUM(
TRANSPOSE(
_apply_frequency_weight(
SORT(FILTER(3 - _var1,  _axis1_filter)))
)
* _apply_custom_weight(
SORT(FILTER(_var2, _axis2_filter))
))




Name
Referes to




_data
=Sheet1!$A$2:$D$11


_data_col
=LAMBDA(col, _choosecol(_data, col))


_choosecol
=LAMBDA(array,col, TAKE(DROP(array,,col-1),,1))






_filter1
=_data_col(1)


_filter2
=_data_col(2)


_var1
=_data_col(3)


_var2
=_data_col(4)






_axis1_filter
=(_filter1=1)*(_var1<3)


_axis2_filter
=(_filter2=1)*(_filter1=1)






_distinct_count returns unique values with counts
=LAMBDA(a, LET(u, UNIQUE(a), freq, DROP(FREQUENCY(a, u),-1), HSTACK(u,  freq)))


_frequency_weights
=LAMBDA(distinct_counts,   LET(counts, TAKE(distinct_counts,,-1), counts/SUM(counts)))






_apply_custom_weight
=LAMBDA(arr, LET( _value_count,  _distinct_count(arr), _counts,  TAKE(_value_count,, -1), _counts * (50  - TAKE(_value_count,,1)) ))


_apply_frequency_weight
=LAMBDA(arr, LET( value_count,  _distinct_count(arr),   TAKE(value_count,,1) * _frequency_weights(value_count) ))



The result is different, because I'm using the count after applying both filters for var1 (instead of just COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11, 1)):

Also, found this comment here about performance of  CHOOSECOLS etc.
